# How to remove record from the database with the foreign key set to NULL

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a c# code to delete one record from the SQLite table. After deleting the record   with `account.UserFunctions.Remove(toRemove);` the record stays in the database with the foreign key set to NULL. How can I completely remove that record from the database programmatically.

```
public AccountResponse DeleteFunction(int id, UpdateUserFunctionRequest functionReq)
{
    var account = getAccount(id);

    Function toRemove = null;
    // Purge all schedules & UserFunctions  - we don't know which were changed
    foreach (var item in account.UserFunctions)
    {

        if (item.UserFunction == functionReq.UserFunction)
        {
            toRemove = item;
            break; // Found
        }

    }
    if(toRemove != null)
    {
        _context.UserFunctions.Attach(toRemove);
        account.UserFunctions.Remove(toRemove);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    //account.Updated = DateTime.UtcNow;
    //_context.UserFunctions.RemoveRange(_context.UserFunctions);

    return _mapper.Map<AccountResponse>(account);
}
```

Comment: If you are using EF, just add DeleteBehavior to your entity to CASCADE
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete

Comment: Can you give me an example how to do that. My database scripts were made by : dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate util. Do I modify them?

Comment: You should have a ```Database Context``` in your code, which should inherit ```DbContext``` which has a built-in ```protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)``` method. From here you can find an example in the link I provided. If this still doesn't make any sense, just take some time and watch EF tutorial, which will cover most of the things you need to know.

Comment: Remember that I want to delete the child item not the parent. Will your solution work for that?

Comment: Just do ```_context.UserFunctions.Remove(toRemove);``` this will remove the entity from database.